# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to upgrade "pip" or "install pywinusb"

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to upgrade pip, and also install pywinusb, but I'm getting the error: "**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)**".

Pip upgrade:

```
PS C:\Python27> pip --version
pip 18.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)

PS C:\Python27> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 836, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 895, in _download_http_url
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And in "pywinusb" install:

```
PS C:\Python27> pip install pywinusb
Collecting pywinusb
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 836, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 895, in _download_http_url
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, filename)
  File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Before this I have installed the package "pyusb" without any problem, without getting any error.

I've searched in google for this error, but not getting a very good explanation.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Seems like pip is trying to manage file in a path that contains "special" (non-ASCII) characters (that's why it says `ordinal not in range(128)`). When "creating" the path, it appends two strings (`str`) and sees that i can't because of that.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, I mean, the current working directory for pip upgrade is "C:\Python27", correct? Is where the command "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" is getting all the python files to do the upgrade? There I don't have any non ASCII character... What is the best way to debug this?

Comment: `pip` is probably using another (temporary) directory to do this. Do you have non-ASCII characters in your personal (/home/you or C:/Users/you/AppData) directory name?

Comment: You are right, I had my personal directory name with an "é", I mean, my name was as "C:/Users/Sérgio Neves". I changed to "C:/Users/SergioNeves", and now pip have upgraded without problem... Never thought that the user name could do this... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if your current working directory has name with non ASCII characters.Example ¢, Ë, Ñ, ß etc.
Remove those from the directory or file name and you are good to go.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, I mean, the current working directory for pip upgrade is "C:\Python27", correct? Is where the command "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" is getting all the python files to do the upgrade? There I don't have any non ASCII character... What is the best way to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

About this particular error: "**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)**", when trying to upgrade pip or install any python packet, was related to the user folder name.

My user folder name was "C:/Users/Sérgio Neves", and the "é" in "Sérgio" was the problem, so I changed the user folder name to "C:/Users/SergioNeves", without any accent and space.

I followed this video to change the folder name:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_rTOA4gXJI